# Label and \label and \eqref

Tags: equations, cross-referencing, numbering

I am writing a lengthy paper. So far I have been using \label{...} and \eqref{...}.

This makes the counter of the referenced equations to be increased by one across all sections and subsections.

But what I want, is that the counter of the references equations begins with the associated section and subsection number.

Comment: `\numberwithin{equation}{section}`? For it you need to load `amsmath` package.

Comment: Thats exactly what I wanted! Great! Many thanks.